# how to hide a string in an BMP image (Steganography)?

Tags: mips, steganography, mars-simulator

I have to do steganography program using MIPS mars simulator. but i'm having a problem on how do i encode the image and how do i put my message(string) in the image .Also the image has to be in a BMP format and coded in 24 bits (8 bits for red , 8 bits for blue and 8 bits for green).
So if anyone can help me by showing me the code or telling me how to do it .I will be grateful.

update: this is what i managed to do. the problem now is how to transform the string into binary and encode it in the image

```
.data
fin:    .asciiz "1.BMP"
fout:   .asciiz "1_out.BMP"
addr: .space 250000
input: .space 20   
str1:  .asciiz "entrez une chaine de caracteres  :"
    .text

main:
str:
    #lire la chaine
    la $a0, str1    
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    #enregistrer la chaine
    li $v0, 8       
    la $a0, input  
    li $a1, 20      

    move $t0, $a0   
    syscall

img:
# ouverture du fichier
li   $v0, 13       
la   $a0, fin     
li   $a1, 0        
li   $a2, 0
syscall           
move $s6, $v0      

# lire le fichier
li   $v0, 14       
move $a0, $s6       
la   $a1, addr   
li   $a2, 230454     
syscall            

# fermeture du fichier 
li   $v0, 16       
move $a0, $s6      
syscall            

#print le fichier
li   $v0, 13       
la   $a0, fout      
li   $a1, 1        
li   $a2, 0
syscall            
move $s6, $v0       

# lire le fichier
li   $v0, 15       
move $a0, $s6      
la   $a1, addr   
li   $a2, 230454     
syscall            

 # fermeture du fichier
li   $v0, 16       
move $a0, $s6      
syscall            

#fin de programme
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: I imagine there are tutorials out there for writing a basic steganography process, I'd take one of those work through converting it to your language of choice. I'm afraid this question is probably too broad for StackOverflow, you may want to give it a try first and then post if you have any specific problems.

Comment: i couldn't find a tutorial for it on Mips so if you can link me one it would be amazing

Comment: @kkhater And you likely won't--the point is the algorithm; translating it to ASM is the easy part. Personally I think you should just figure it out and do your own work--that's kind of the point.

Answer (score 0):

The .BMP [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) is not incredibly complicated (fortunately).

Considering that you're operating on such a low level, I would recommend (if security isn't a huge issue) that you [mask](https://think4dev.wordpress.com/tag/masking-of-bits-in-mips/) the last bit of each pixel to your data. Simply jump past the data headers directly into the image data and begin changing the least significant bit of each RGB color to the next bit of your embedded message. Be advised that there is some padding that occurs in BMP format, so it would be best to keep a counter of how many bytes you've already masked in the current row so you don't affect the padding 0's. This method requires an 8/1 ratio of data sizes.

Additionally, you could use a [Shift Logical Right](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~davis/cpeg222/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-12/ass12_6.html) loop in MIPS to determine the target bit to embed in your image. Mask each loop iteration with the number 1 `and $bitToEmbed, $yourMessageByte, 1` to determine the bit to embed and move to the next byte after 8 iterations (8 bits per byte).

A single masking operation may look like (Actual register names must be substituted, of course):

```
and $bitToEmbed, $yourMessageByte, 1  #Get Target Bit to embed
and $RGBByte, $RGBByte, 254           #Mask the RGB Byte with 11111110
or $RGBByte, $bitToEmbed, $RGBByte    #Embed your target bit.
```

Add some iteration to go over a single whole Message Byte:

```
#Jump Past Header...
#Create all temporary versions of your image and message...
#Begin data processing:
ITERBYTE:
    and $bitToEmbed, $yourMessageByte, 1  #Get Target Bit to embed
    and $RGBByte, $RGBByte, 254           #Mask the RGB Byte with 11111110
    or $RGBByte, $bitToEmbed, $RGBByte    #Embed your target bit.
    srl $yourMessageByte, $yourMessageByte, 1 #Bitshift right by one...
    addi $counter, $counter, 1            #Increment counter
    bne $counter, $BitsInByte, ITERBYTE   #continue loop if we have not read the whole byte
```

The security of this method relies on the fact that most people cannot tell the difference between slightly different shades of the same color. (Could you tell me if this text is `#000000` or `#000001`)?

Please note, however, that there are methods to detect this level of stenography, as it is not highly sophisticated. Generally it involves computers scanning for the average noise of images or comparing existing images to their modified counterparts. However, if you simply need something that is not human detectable (or readable), then this is a great solution.

Comment: Hopefully you'll be there for his tests, too.

Comment: can you please explain it more simply